# Adding a type to an existing template with out it being dropped c++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

My goal is to be able to include my own extra type at declaration and have it passed to my template function. How would I be able to declare my type so that the compiler would not drop my extra template parameter.

### For example I have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// my_vector is an alias for std::vector<T> that also takes an extra type E
template<typename T, typename E>
using my_vector = std::vector<T>;

// my aliased type is being demoted to std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> >
template<typename T, typename E>
void write_to(std::ostream stream, const my_vector<T, E>& vec) {
        // I need E type for somthing here for example this
        stream << static_cast<E>(vec.size());
        for (auto elm : vec) {
                stream << elm;
        }
}

int main() {
        // very redundantly declaring that I want my_vector
        my_vector<float, uint8_t> vec = my_vector<float, uint8_t>{ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
        write_to(std::cout, vec); 
        // this would compile if I called write_to<uint8_t> but I want this to be assumed by the compiler
}
```

g++ output suggests that it is not passing `my_vector<T, E>` to write_to but instead drops my_vector altogether and instead passes `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T> >`, is it possible to get the compiler to not drop the extra template parameter so that I dont have to explicitly include it in every call of `write_to` here?

### Here is my output from g++ std=c++17

```
[arkav:~/devel/packetize] $g++ template_demote.cc --std=c++17
template_demote.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
template_demote.cc:21:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘write_to(std::ostream&, my_vector<float, unsigned char>&)’
   21 |  write_to(std::cout, vec); // this would compile if I called write_to<uint8_t> but I want this to be assumed by the compiler
      |                         ^
template_demote.cc:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class E> void write_to(std::ostream, my_vector<T, E>&)’
   10 | void write_to(std::ostream stream, const my_vector<T, E>& vec) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~
template_demote.cc:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
template_demote.cc:21:25: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘E’
   21 |  write_to(std::cout, vec); // this would compile if I called write_to<uint8_t> but I want this to be assumed by the compiler
      |                         ^
```

### Solution

Inherent std::vector and its constructor in my type definition

```cpp
template<typename E, typename T>
class my_vector: public std::vector {
        using std::vector<T>::vector;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) that, when aliasing:

> Alias templates are never deduced by template argument deduction when deducing a template template parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that. I solved it by inheriting std::vector instead and Ill edit my question with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class E>
struct util {
    std::vector<T> my_vector;

    void write_to(std::ostream& stream) {
        stream << static_cast<E>(my_vector.size());
        for (auto elm : my_vector) {
                stream << elm;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    util<float, uint8_t> u;
    u.my_vector = std::vector<float>{ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    u.write_to(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but write_to in my codebase is a function in a class with other overloads. It also adds the need to access `my_vector` as a member of `u`.